# office-js: Uncaught TypeError: window.external.GetContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, office365, office365-apps, office-js

I'm struggeling to check if my hosted web application is opened by a browser or in the Outlook 2013/2016 client.

This is my approach:

```
/**
 * Check if the app is running in outlook
 */
$rootScope.isOutlook = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
        Office.initialize = function() {
            var hostType = Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName;
            if (hostType === "Outlook" || hostType === "Mac Outlook" || hostType === "OutlookWebApp") {
                $rootScope.isOutlook = true;
            }
        };
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof TypeError) {
            // catch error if web app is opened in browser.
            console.log('Not in office context! Generated error: ' + e);
        }
    }
});
$log.debug('isOutlook: ' + $rootScope.isOutlook);
```

The function itself works like a charm, but I can't get rid of the 'Uncaught TypeError'.
It keeps throwing me this Uncaught TypeError in the console of my browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.external.GetContext is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName is telling you which type of Office host you have. But it seems like maybe you are trying to run the same app both inside of an Office host and as a completely standalone web page.

There is a [post by Simon J.K. Pedersen](http://wp.sjkp.dk/how-to-detect-if-an-app-for-office-is-opened-from-office/) about that scenario, which involves checking if that same window.external.GetContext function exists. This is not documented.

```
 Office.initialize = init;
 try {
     if (!window.external.GetContext) {
         $rootScope.isOutlook = false;
         init(); // Manually call init
     }
 } catch (e) {
     // when in office context unable to access external.
 }
```

You could also do something like include a query string parameter in your Office manifest and check that so that you know it's coming from Office.